# python print statement with utf-8 and nohup

Tags: python, utf-8, nohup

I have a some python code that prints log messages.  When run at the command line, it does fine with utf-8.  Log messages that contain special characters print out fine.  However, when run in the background under nohup, it barfs on utf-8 characters.

```
nohup python2.7 myProgram.py &
```

The error I see is the usual "try to encode utf in ascii" error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec
>   can't encode character u'\u2013' in
>   position 71: ordinal not in range(128)

I assume this is because nohup signals to python that it doesn't have a normal terminal, so it defaults to ascii.  Is there any way to either tell nohup to run with utf-8 enabled or to set this up so that utf-8 characters won't cause a crash when running under nohup in the background?

Comment: do you have the encoding header? `# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-` as first or second line in the file.

Comment: Post you script, especially a couple of first lines and some example of log messages that fail.

Comment: Another option is to use 'screen' instead of 'nohup' http://serverfault.com/a/311602/10905

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [PYTHONIOENCODING](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING):

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
nohup python2.7 myProgram.py &
```

---

For example, if

**myProgram.py**:

```
unicode_obj=u'\N{INFINITY}'
print(unicode_obj)
```

then running

```
nohup python2.7 myProgram.py > /tmp/test &
```

produces

**/tmp/test**:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u221e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
nohup python2.7 myProgram.py > /tmp/test &
```

produces

**/tmp/test**:

```
∞
```

Comment: awesome!  Thanks!  I spent forever looking at LC_* env variables, I didn't know it had to be python specific.  Sweet

Comment: Tempted to downvote because you're supposed to handle encodings correctly in the script. (ie, encode the unicode string to the expected encoding, and write that to stdout).

Comment: @Arafangion: what is the expected encoding of a file used for redirection?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I don't know - that's your job. (Hint: On *my* system, I tend to prefer UTF-8, however, other people and other systems have different encodings), but even so, your answer is still wrong if you have non-UTF-8 encoded data in your python strings, your answer only influences the default encoding used for unicode -> string conversions.

Comment: I've set and exported that environment variable

    (PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8) 

on a few scripts and it not resolve that error.  In the end there were problems in the code that needed to be resolved too.